# variable undefined when console.log before export component React-Native Functional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

the problem is this:

I have a global variable (outside componentA definition) let name: string for example, I need to assign a value after fetch it from backend in the useEffect [], and use it before the component is exported, but at that time the variable is undefined, there is any way to do it or something like that?

this is a code example

```
import React from 'react'

let name: string

const ComponentA = () => {
 useEffect(() => {
  fetchName()
 }, [])

 const fechName = async () => {
  const _name = await backendService.getName()
  name = _name
 }

 return (
  <>Anything</>
 )
}

console.log("name: ", name) // getting undefined


export default ComponentA
```

EDIT: The thing is, i am implementing Codepush, and this must be applied when component is exported, like that:
`export default CodePush({option: name})(ComponentA)`, so i want to set that option attribute dinamically, gettting it from backend

Comment: Why not fetch from the backend outside of the component?

Comment: not able to do that

Comment: What are you going to use the name for?

Comment: Why don't use the name for dependency array? You are using async function. You should follow the changing name!

Comment: What's the purpose of this? You can have multiple of the same component on a page, so what do you expect `name` to be?

Comment: This is just an example, the file code is too large to post here, and will be not understable

Comment: But the thing is, i am implementing Codepush, and this must be applied when component is exported, like that: 
`export default CodePush({option: name})(ComponentA)`, so i want to set that option attribute dinamically, gettting it from backend

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are assigning `name` to itself, and since it is `undefined`, it will always stay undefined. Make sure to assign `name` to `_name` instead

```
 const fechName = async () => {
  const _name = await backendService.getName()
  name = _name
 }
```

EDIT: BTW, even with this change, you will still see `undefined` in the console.log because the console.log statement is executed before the name variable is assigned a value inside the `fetchName` function. Try moving the console.log into `fetchName` after the `name` assignment.

Comment: True, but this doesn't really solve the issue at large

Comment: edited, your right, but thats not the focused problem

Comment: Yes you are right, i understand that, but i need to do something like that, the thing is, i am implementing Codepush, and this must be applied when component is exported, like that: 
`export default CodePush({option: name})(ComponentA)`, so i want to set that option attribute dinamically, gettting it from backend

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), the point should be **how to create component dynamically**, you can do something like this:

```
export async function createComponentA() {
    const name = await getOptionName()

    return CodePush({option: name})(ComponentA)
}
```

the returned component may need a `useMemo` to avoid re-fetch too many times